# Powershell code for Text to column from CSV

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

[Text to column in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O85H.png)

Problem:I have data like as above in hyperlink image in excel with headers , i need power shell code to split it columns delimited by comma , i can do it on excel by manually but every time i don't want to do such activity ,so any help is much appreciated.

[Check code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrhha.png)
## Power Shell Code ##

worksheet.QueryTables.add(TxtConnector,worksheet.Range("A1"))

Comment: Can you please demonstrate your existing attempt. Hint- use import-csv

Comment: @OwlsSleeping Its somewhat hard to explain, anyway will try to brief it, there is one CSV file which one column includes commas i tried to convert csv into excel and  creating a query table pointing to this CSV till this step i'm succeeded but all data coming in one column without text to columns .

Comment: `Import-Csv -Path 'TheCsvInputFile.csv' | Export-Csv -Path 'TheNewCsvFile.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation`. This will create a new csv file with the same delimiter characters your local Excel expects.

Comment: @Theo there's error coming like "The process cannot access the file XXX is being used by other process.

Comment: @amarnadh It cannot be opened in Excel while you are converting it..

Comment: @Theo i got you, but i need to take this data from Excel (.xls) only with text to columns, I tried to export xls its working but all data comes in first column need to do  text to columns.

Comment: Your input looks extremely strange.  The content looks like the content of a CSV file.  It looks like it was read  into excel the wrong way.  If you had this same data in SomeFile.csv,   and just read this in with Excel,  it should come out with each field in a column.

Answer (score 0):

you can use text to column option in the excel itself for this.
open the File in excel and Go to DATA Tab,

```
1. Select the Column
2. Data -> Text to columns
3. Delimiter ',' OK
4. Data Split to all columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what's the input (xls/csv file?) and what you're trying to archieve?

For what i could understand, you can use `import-csv -delimiter ","` to force it to divide the columns by comma.
If you need it back on a csv, you can pipe the result to `export-csv -path $path -useculture`, which will use the delimiters set by your current culture. You can also use any other kind of delimiter by using the `-delimiter` switch.

If this isn't what you were looking for, could you paste your code in the original post instead of using an image? It'll make it easier to read and test :)